# Scala mixins with same parametrized types

Tags: design-patterns, scala

I'm very new to scala and the quest of adapting scala specific patterns is on going.
The goal is to separate messages proccessing and message generation. There is base covariant parametrized type representing a message handling. The specific realization may be combained by regular mixin or by mixing underlying protocols.

The requirments are:

1. Extend as simaple as possible
2. Be type-safe to prevent stupid mistakes

I've come with the clean sample code (contains both definition and using):

```
trait Protocol

trait Handler [+proto <: Protocol] {
  def handle : PartialFunction[Protocol,Unit] 
  /* can not name the actual protocol type since handler for a subtype also fully supports handling supertype
besides any message extends other subtype ot the supertype since the scala use matching with case classes
and these algebraic type realization is seemed excluded from strait scala type system
  */
}

/*
==============
using scenario
==============
*/

trait SumMsg extends Protocol
case class Sum(op : Int) extends SumMsg
case class Sub(op : Int) extends SumMsg

trait ProdMsg extends Protocol
case class Mul(op : Int) extends ProdMsg
case class Diff(op : Int) extends ProdMsg {
  require (0 != op, "Division by zero is not permited")
}

/* stackable traites */
trait NullHandler {
  def handle : PartialFunction[Protocol,Unit] = { case _ => {} }
}

trait SumHandler extends Handler [SumMsg] with NullHandler{
  var store : Int
  abstract override def handle : PartialFunction[Protocol,Unit] = ({
case Sum(op) => { this.store += op}
case Sub(op) => { this.store -= op}
  }: PartialFunction[Protocol,Unit]) orElse super.handle
}

trait MulHandler extends Handler [ProdMsg] with NullHandler{
  var store : Int
  abstract override def handle : PartialFunction[Protocol,Unit] = ({
case Mul(op) => {this.store *= op}
case Diff(op) => {this.store /= op}
  }: PartialFunction[Protocol,Unit]) orElse super.handle
}

/* concrete classes */
class SumAccum (var store: Int) extends SumHandler

class MulAccum (var store: Int) extends MulHandler

class ArithmAccum (var store: Int) extends SumHandler with MulHandler

/* producers */
class ProduceSums (val accum : Handler [SumMsg]) {
  var state : Boolean = true
  def touch() = if (this.state)
{
  this.state = false
  this.accum.handle(Sum(2))
} else {
  this.state = true
  this.accum.handle(Sub(1))
}
}

class ProduceProds (val accum : Handler [ProdMsg]) {
  var state : Boolean = true
  def touch() = if (this.state)
{
  this.state = false
  this.accum.handle(Mul(2))
} else {
  this.state = true
  this.accum.handle(Diff(2))
}
}

/* tying together via cake pattern */
trait ProtocolComp {
  type Proto <: Protocol
}

trait ProducerComp { this: ProtocolComp =>
  type ProducerT <: {def touch()}
  def getProducer(accum : Handler[Proto]) : ProducerT
}

trait HandlerComp { this: ProtocolComp =>
  type HandlerT <: Handler[Proto]
  def getHandler(store:Int) : HandlerT
}

trait AppComp extends ProtocolComp with ProducerComp with HandlerComp {
  val initStore = 1
  def test() {
val handler = getHandler(initStore)
val producer = getProducer(handler)
producer.touch()
  }
}

/* different examples of compositions */

/* correct usage */

object One extends AppComp{
  override type Proto = SumMsg
  override type ProducerT = ProduceSums
  override type HandlerT = SumAccum
  override def getProducer(accum : Handler[Proto]) = new ProduceSums(accum)
  override def getHandler(store : Int) = new SumAccum(store)
}

object Two extends AppComp{
  override type Proto = SumMsg
  override type ProducerT = ProduceSums
  override type HandlerT = ArithmAccum
  override def getProducer(accum : Handler[Proto]) = new ProduceSums(accum)
  override def getHandler(store : Int) = new ArithmAccum(store)
}

object Three extends AppComp{
  override type Proto = SumMsg with ProdMsg
  override type ProducerT = ProduceSums
  override type HandlerT = ArithmAccum
  override def getProducer(accum : Handler[Proto]) = new ProduceSums(accum)
  override def getHandler(store : Int) = new ArithmAccum(store)
}

/* incorrect usage
static type checking protects from some kind of logic errors
*/

object Four extends AppComp{
  override type Proto = SumMsg
  override type ProducerT = ProduceProds
  override type HandlerT = SumAccum
  override def getProducer(accum : Handler[Proto]) = new ProduceProds(accum)
  override def getHandler(store : Int) = new SumAccum(store)
}
```

Last example is not well typed and gives an error as expected:

```
mixed.scala:140: error: type mismatch;
found   : Handler[Four.Proto]
required: Handler[ProdMsg]
  override def getProducer(accum : Handler[Proto]) = new ProduceProds(accum)
```

I've build a flexible system with simple combining and extending, yet as typesafe as possible for using scala's case classes instead of alegraic types

I've almost achieve my goal, but met a big scala misfunction: type erasure of underlying jvm. The constructions I've used is illegal for scala since I want parametrized trait be extendiable with "with" clause.

Compiler complaining about

```
mixed.scala:53: error: illegal inheritance;
class ArithmAccum inherits different type instances of trait Handler:
Handler[ProdMsg] and Handler[SumMsg]
class ArithmAccum (var store: Int) extends SumHandler with MulHandler
```

What options do I have? I can't use the pattern I've designed and need to find an equal replacement by usability. May anoyone suggest alternative source code solution? Is there a scala plugin (they seemed to exist for compiler) or another method to change backends for scala parametrized types from java generics to c++ like code generation?

Comment: I have the same problem. F**k JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not the type erasure of the JVM but Scala's use of linearization for resolving inheritance.

Remove the type parameter [+proto <: Protocol] from Handler. It isn't used by the handle method, anyway. Then your illegal inheritance error will go away.

Comment: but I'll lost type safety this way. The fourth example will compile while being illegal

Comment: But your type safety is only imaginary anyway. The handle method is not using the type parameter proto, therefore you cannot ensure that a Handler[A] can really handle protocols of type A.

Comment: Also, I don't think your current solution works as you intended. In object Three you define type Proto = SumMsg with ProdMsg. That means it only accepts protocols that are both Sums *and* Prods. But what you probably want is Sums *or* Prods. If I remember correctly you cannot easily encode such a type in Scala.

Comment: Handle if covariant so a `Handler[SumMsg with ProdMsg]` is a subtype of `Handler[SumMsg]` and using it instead is correct. I can't imply concrete types for method handle since it would not be covariant in that case. So I had to use untyped `PartialFunction[Protocol,Unit]` instead of `PartialFunction[proto,Unit]`. This example is rather syntethic, in real code I use Akka's actors for message distribution and akka's receive type signature ( PartialFunction[Any,Unit] ) is other restriction

Comment: Sorry, I did not consider that Handler is covariant. But have you considered that this means that you can supply a Handler[Sum] where you need a Handler[SumMsg]? I cannot imagine this is really what you want.

Comment: Yes, I've considered. It's a big drawback and I don to know how to replace case classes with something more suitable. Not allowing parametrization with case class instead of protocol trait is enforced by agreement. I can't find suitable algebraic type representation in scala